# How to render Blazor component with RenderFragment Parameter from Razor Page

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-component

I have following Blazor component:

## Button.razor

```
<button params...>
    @ChildContent
</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use it in the Razor page. I know I can use:
`@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Button>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))` for that.
But how do I pass the `RenderFragment` parameter to this component? The `RenderComponentAsunc`
has a second argument where I can pass parameters for component so I think something like this
should be possible:

## Page.cshtml

```cs
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Button>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new
{
    ChildContent = "Button text"
}))
```

However this ends with error:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment'.
```

So I tried to pass `RenderFragment` directly. I created extension method that create `RenderFragment` from string:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static RenderFragment ToRenderFragment(this string s) => b => b.AddContent(0, s);
}
```

And then render it this way:

```cs
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Button>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new
{
    ChildContent = "Button text".ToRenderFragment()
}))
```

I wasn't successful with this approach either.

```
NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment' instances are not supported.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment' instances are not supported.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment' instances are not supported.
```

The component can be also rendered with using `<component>` tag. So I tried it.

```cs
<component type="typeof(Button)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered">
    Button text    
</component>
```

But this renders html incorrectly

```cs
<button></button>
Button text
```

And I want

```cs
<button>
    Button text
</button>
```

How to do that? I am using button as simplied example here so direct use of markup in the `.cshtml` file would be inconvenient duplication of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a parameter of type [`MarkupString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.markupstring?view=aspnetcore-7.0), which supports HTML content. In the blazor component you can just say `@MyMarkupString` and it'll be rendered as HTML.

If you do want to use the `RenderFragment`, you can use a normal `string` as parameter. Then in the component itself, you can call the `ToRenderFragment` on that `string`, if it has a value.

Both of these options should work around the `NotSupportedException` you got as `string` and `MarkupString` are serializable.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. However, I was wondering if it's possible to do that without additional parameters on the component itself. The component is used 95% of the time in the Blazor and having two options on how to pass child content seems wrong to me. If  I add the parameter of type string (or MarkupString) then in Blazor I can write both: `<Button>Text</Button>`  and `<Button Content="Text" />`and I am sure in the long term will somebody use both options leading to inconsistencies in the code.

Comment: @wujido yeah that's understandable. But I don't think it's possible in another way...